# using foreach inside a class in php

Tags: php

```
class User{
    protected $dates =[
        'created'
    ];
    public function __construct(){
        foreach( $this->dates as $date){
            $property = $this->{$date};
            $this->{$date} = new DateTime($property);
        }
    }
}
```

1) Is using "this" with "date" variable in the foreach loop inside a class specific to php or a general oops concept?

2) why do we need curly braces with "this" can't we simply write $this->date ?

Comment: oh we dont need curly braces at all but why do we require $date why not only date like $this->dates

Comment: "can't we simply write $this->date"  You _can_, but it won't give you the same result.

Comment: can you please a tell the difference or a reference where i can read about it

Comment: The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) would be a good place to start.

Comment: I am following a video tutorial, reading the documentation will be a way difficult job for me.

Comment: ...but you asked for a reference to READ about it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->{$date}` is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). It uses the value of `$date` as the name of a property to access. So when `$date = "created"` (as it is when iterating through the `$this->dates` property), it's equivalent to `$this->created`.

You don't need the curly braces if the expression is just a variable name, you can write `$this->$date`; but if it's a more complex expresion you need the braces, e.g. `$this->{$date . "_field"} would be equivalent to`$this->created_field`. But many programmers use the braces consistently, just to make the code clearer and cause a warning if they forget the`$`.

You need the `$` to make it use a variable as the property name. If you just write `$this->date` it looks for the `date` property, not the `created` property.

Using dynamic property names like this is available in many scripting languages; for instance, you can do it in Javascript with `this[date]`. It's not generally available in statically-typed languages like C++.

Comment: thanks for that exactly the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$this->{$date} , assuming your date is '2018-08-13', for example, you're trying to acess $this->2018-08-13.

I think what you want is

```
 foreach($this->dates as $date){
     //DO SOMETHING LIKE INITIATE THE OBJ
     $obj->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //If you want current time
    // OR
     $obj->date = $date; //For the value on $date
    }
```

Comment: `$date` is the string `"created"`.

Comment: Yes, but it looks like he doesn't have a clue of what foreach does.

Comment: i know exactly what foreach does , question was about php syntax not foreach

Answer (score 0):

Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names. The variable property name will be resolved within the scope from which the call is made. For instance, if you have an expression such as $foo->$bar, then the local scope will be examined for $bar and its value will be used as the name of the property of $foo.

For Example:

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
?>
```

$this->var is used when you have actual property declared in class ($var above)

whereas $this->$date in your case will be used when you are not declaring property in the class and would like to still use it has a class property...

In order to use $this->dates you will need to declare a class variable like

```
class {
   public $dates;

   public function __construct($d){
       $this->dates = $d;
   }
}
```

$this->{$date} will be interpreted as **$this->created**